# What am i missing here? Angularjs ionic sliders

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using the sliders in the ionic framework and everything is working great. This is my html:

```
<ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" show-pager={{showPager}}>
```

Pretty straightforward, notice that i am using showPager to dynamically show and hide the pager.

And in the controller:

```
$scope.showPager = true

$scope.slideHasChanged = ($index) ->
    if $index == 4
      $scope.$apply ->
        $scope.showPager = false
```

It does as expected sets showPager value to false when the index of the slide is 4 in the web console.

BUT it does not really hide it on the web page. IF i explicitly set showPager to false, it does not display in the browser as expected, but if i try the above stuff to dynamically hide it, it does not work.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ion-slide-box>` directive does not observe `show-pager` attribute. So it will consider only the value which was at the time of directive initialization.

For your use-case, you can show/hide pager by putting `ng-class` directive on `<ion-slide-box>` directive and based on that class you can write css to show/hide the pager.

Check this example [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPvmjB) for working example.